# Will memcpy or memmove cause problems copying classes?

Tags: c++, class, memcpy, memmove

Suppose I have any kind of class or structure.  No virtual functions or anything, just some custom constructors, as well as a few pointers that would require cleanup in the destructor.

Would there be any adverse affects to using memcpy or memmove on this structure?  Will deleting a moved structure cause problems?  The question assumes that the memory alignment is also correct, and we are copying to safe memory.

Comment: The natural question is *why*?

Comment: Agree with @JonathonReinhart why not just create a new one. For the simple reason it will make the code more readable in X years time

Comment: Let me guess. You were just wondering? Short answer, don't. Implement a clone function like .NET

Comment: @Cole : What? As opposed to a copy constructor?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I think `clone` existed before .NET :-)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It's an array of objects, which requires sorting based on a member.  I can also guarantee no extra external references to the object.

Comment: @AdrianCornish I know it existed before, but as a C# guy, I just think to .NET and not other languages

Comment: @Serge: your job is to write correct and clear code, optimizing it is the compiler's job.

Comment: @Serge: "requires sorting based on a member" - why is sorting relevant? If you use the Standard Library `sort` routine you can avoid `memcpy`/`memmove`....

Comment: @ColeJohnson Sorry could not resist the jibe - I like being a near metal programmer ;-)

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, guys (and gals?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the general case, yes, there will be problems. Both `memcpy` and `memmove` are bitwise operations with no further semantics. That might not be sufficient to *move* the object<sup>*</sup>, and it is clearly not enough to *copy*.

In the case of the copy it will break as multiple objects will be referring to the same dynamically allocated memory, and more than one destructor will try to release it. Note that solutions like `shared_ptr` will not help here, as sharing ownership is part of the *further semantics* that `memcpy`/`memmove` don't offer.

For *moving*, and depending on the type you might get away with it in some cases. But it won't work if the objects hold pointers/references to the elements being moved (including self-references) as the pointers will be bitwise copied (again, no *further semantics* of copying/moving) and will refer to the old locations.

The general answer is still the same: **don't**.

---

<sup>*</sup> Don't take *move* here in the exact C++11 sense. I have seen an implementation of the standard library containers that used special tags to enable *moving* objects while growing buffers through the use of `memcpy`, but it required explicit annotations in the stored types that marked the objects as *safely movable through `memcpy`*, after the objects were placed in the new buffer the old buffer was discarded **without** calling any destructors (C++11 *move* requires leaving the object in a *destructible* state, which cannot be achieved through this hack)

Answer (score 5):

Generally using memcpy on a class based object is not a good idea. The most likely problem would be copying a pointer and then deleting it.  You should use a copy constructor or assignment operator instead.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment that using `memcpy` is not a good idea. Re the "on an object", note that `memcpy` can only be used on objects. So it's a bit redundant.

Comment: If you consider primitives to be objects, then yes that statement is true.

Comment: this question is about C++, and the C++ standard defines what `object` is -- there is no room for personal opinion. check it out. and *please don't use Java terminology (or whatever it is) in an answer to a C++ question*.

Comment: For reference: 1.8 The C++ object model "An object is a
region of storage."  By primitives, I meant scalar variables which are actually objects by definition. I have edited the original post to express my original intent of class based objects.  Although it would seem that, Wikipedia needs some editing as it says, "Objects are instances of classes created at runtime"

Comment: +1 for research. :-) well, it's not perfect yet, but nothing's prefect. class based objects include POD objects (like simple C `struct`); you probably meant non-POD objects. or corresponding more refined terminology for C++11. it gets complicated...

Answer (score 4):

No, don't do this.

If you `memcpy` a structure whose destructor deletes a pointer within itself, you'l wind up doing a double delete when the second instance of the structure is destroyed in whatever manner.

The C++ idiom is copy constructor for classes and `std::copy` or any of its friends for copying ranges/sequences/containers.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C++11, you can use [std::is_trivially_copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) to determine if an object can be copied or moved using `memcpy` or `memmove`. From the documentation:

> Objects of trivially-copyable types are the only C++ objects that may
>   be safely copied with std::memcpy or serialized to/from binary files
>   with std::ofstream::write()/std::ifstream::read(). In general, a
>   trivially copyable type is any type for which the underlying bytes can
>   be copied to an array of char or unsigned char and into a new object
>   of the same type, and the resulting object would have the same value
>   as the original.

Many classes don't fit this description, and you must beware that classes can change. I would suggest that if you are going to use `memcpy`/`memmove` on C++ objects, that you somehow protect unwanted usage. For example, if you're implementing a container class, it's easy for the type that the container holds to be modified, such that it is no longer trivially copyable (eg. somebody adds a virtual function). You could do this with a `static_assert`:

```
template<typename T>
class MemcopyableArray
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value, "MemcopyableArray used with object type that is not trivially copyable.");
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Aside from safety, which is the most important issue as the other answers have already pointed out, there may also be an issue of performance, especially for small objects.

Even for simple POD types, you may discover that doing proper initialization in the initializer list of your copy constructor (or assignments in the assignment operator depending on your usage) is actually faster than even an intrinsic version of `memcpy`. This may very well be due to memcpy's entry code which may check for word alignment, overlaps, buffer/memory access rights, etc.... In Visual C++ 10.0 and higher, to give you a specific example, you would be surprised by how much preamble code that tests *various things* executes before memcpy even begins its logical function.

Comment: So did I, until I actually profiled it. It is very fast for largish objects, which is a very platform specific notion, but horrendously slow for say a <20 byte copy, at least on my platform when compared to just copying the bytes in a for loop.

Comment: +1 for mentioning efficiency. it's all well and good to point out that efficiency should be third place or lower on the list of concerns, but the fact is, not just most beginners but most programmers (misguidedly) think of efficiency first and foremost. and then it really helps to have some correction of the usual incorrect ideas about what's efficient and what isn't. let me just add that if one chooses to use much time on efficiency concerns, then it's also a good idea to **measure**. which you also mention. :-)

Comment: This is a great example of how the biggest enemy of performance is assumptions. No matter what you think you know, measurement is the only truth.