# Shifting array elements to the right with a C++ equivalent of memmove

Tags: c++, arrays

For learning purposes, I'm creating a container, based from an array with map-like functionality.  Every time I insert a key, I want to keep the array ordered.  I have already implemented functions to find where the key should go in the arrays index, the only issue I have currently is efficiently shifting the array elements.

I have a simple loop to do this:

```
for (size_t i = mSize; i > n; i--)
{
    mCont[i] = mCont[i - 1];
}
```

However, I'd like to possibly use something such as memmove to be able to do this quicker -but I'm not sure how to use it- when the container grows in size.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: To do it quicker you should use move semantics

Comment: `memmove` is a C function. Thus is only useful for POD types. You should use `std::copy()` (or if you move semantics `std::move`) which will use the most efficient method for the type being moved (ie if the most efficient method is memmove it will use it).

Comment: This is why memmove cannot be used with non-POD types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135769/will-memcpy-or-memmove-cause-problems-copying-classes

Comment: @LokiAstari: Since he's copying to the right I think [`std::copy_backward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward) makes more sense.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Sure.

Comment: Just because there's a standard function for it doesn't mean it will be *much* more efficient.  All the memory to the right of the insert position has to be read and rewritten, which is is going to take `O(n)` time no matter what you do.  Lowering the constant factor helps, but it still won't make such a container usable (compared to a tree) for very large `n`.  However, you're right that if `mCont` is an array of bytes, a compiler might emit code that operates one byte at a time, in which case `memmove` might beat it by a factor of ~16 or even ~32 on an x86 CPU (if it's in L1 cache).

Comment: consider using a tree structure for your container, then insertion does not involve a bunch of copying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::move_backward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward) :

```
std::move_backward( std::next( std::begin( mCont ), n ), 
                    std::next( std::begin( mCont ), mSize - 1 ),
                    std::next( std::begin( mCont ), mSize ) );
```

Comment: Nice.  I didn't even know that was a standard algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your input