# Using move semantics to avoid copying when pushing_back to a custom container does not avoid copying

Tags: c++11, copy, containers, move-semantics

I have implemented a  custom container (same vein as std::vector) and I am trying to make it so that its 'push_back' function would use leverage on move semantics to avoid creating a copy of whatever is being pushed back - specially when the object to be pushed into the container is returned by an external function.

After reading quite a bit about move semantics and custom containers, I still can't find why my approach is still generating a copy instead of just moving the passed object into the container's inner dynamic array.

Here is a simplified version of my container looks like:

```
template<class T>
class Constructor
{
private:
    size_t size = 0;
    size_t cap = 0;
    T *data = nullptr;

public:
Constructor()
{
    cap = 1;
    size = 0;
    data = static_cast<T*>(malloc(cap * sizeof(T)));
}

~Constructor()
{ delete[] data; }

template<typename U>
void push_back(U &&value)
{
    if (size + 1 >= cap)
    {
        size_t new_cap = (cap * 2);
        T* new_data = static_cast<T*>(malloc(new_cap * sizeof(T)));
        memmove(new_data, data, (size) * sizeof(T));
        for (size_t i = 0; i<cap; i++)
        {
            data[i].~T();
        }

        delete[] data;

        cap = new_cap;
        data = new_data;
        new(data + size) T(std::forward<U>(value));
    }
    else
    {
        new(data + size) T(std::forward<U>(value));
    }

    ++size;
}

const T& operator[](const size_t index) const //access [] overloading
{
    return data[index];
}
};
```

Here is a custom class that will print messages when its instances are created, copied or moved, in order to help debugging:

```
class MyClass
{
size_t id;

public:
MyClass(const size_t new_id)
{
    id = new_id;
    std::cout << "new instance with id " << id << std::endl;
}
MyClass(const MyClass &passedEntity)
{
    id = passedEntity.id;
    std::cout << "copied instance" << std::endl;
}
MyClass(MyClass &&passedEntity)
{
    id = passedEntity.id;
    std::cout << "moved instance" << std::endl;
}

void printID() const
{
    std::cout << "this instance's id is " << id << std::endl;
}
};
```

And here is the external function:

```
MyClass &foo(MyClass &passed)
{
    return passed;
}
```

Lastly, here is the `main` function that runs a test case using the above function and classes to show the problem:

```
int main()
{
MyClass a(33);
std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "Using my custom container: " << std::endl;
Constructor<MyClass> myContainer;
myContainer.push_back(foo(a));
myContainer[0].printID();
std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "Using dinamic array: " << std::endl;
MyClass *dinArray = static_cast<MyClass*>(malloc(1 * sizeof(MyClass)));
dinArray = new(dinArray + 1) MyClass(std::forward<MyClass>(foo(a)));
dinArray[0].printID();
std::cout << std::endl;


system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
new instance with id 33

Using my custom container:
copied instance
this instance's id is 33

Using dinamic array:
moved instance
this instance's id is 33
```

As it can be seen, if the instance of `MyClass` is put directly into a dynamic array, then just the move conmstructor is called and not the copy constructor. However, if I push_back the `yClass` instance into an instance of `Container`, a copy constructor is still being called.

Could someone help me understand what exactly am I doing wrong here? How could I make it so that elements are pushed into the container without generating a copy?

Comment: That's the rationale behind c++11's `emplace_back()`.

Comment: If you want to emulate move semantics in C++03, use std::swap:  `void emplace(vector<T>& v, T& value) { v.resize(v.size()+ 1); std::swap(v.back(), value); }`  You may have to define std::swap for some of your types as well.  A pseudo move constructor of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call this line

```
myContainer.push_back(foo(a));
```

L-value is passed into `push_back` method, and now read about using std::forward - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/forward/,

> Returns an rvalue reference to arg if arg is not an lvalue reference.
>
> If arg is an lvalue reference, the function returns arg without modifying its type.

and in your `push_back` you call

```
new(data + size) T(std::forward<U>(value));
```

but `value` was passed as L-value, and only constructor `MyClass(const MyClass &passedEntity)` can be invoked.

If you want `a` object to be moved, you can write

```
myContainer.push_back(std::move(a)); // cast to R-reference
```

**EDIT**

You should not use move in your `push_back` function, below is simple example.
Suppose you have class like this:

```
 struct Foo {
 int i;
 Foo (int i = 0) : i(i) { 
 }
 ~Foo () { 
 }
 Foo (const Foo& ) { 
 }
 Foo& operator=(const Foo&) { 
    return *this;
 }
 Foo (Foo&& f) 
 { 
    i = f.i; 
    f.i = 0;   // this is important
 }
 Foo& operator=(Foo&& f) 
 {   
    i = f.i; 
    f.i = 0; // this is important
    return *this;
 }
};
```

we have also 2 functions

```
template<class T> 
void process1 (const T& ) {
    cout << "process1" << endl;
}

template<class T>
void process (T&& obj) {
    cout << "process2" << endl;
    T newObj = forward<T>(obj);
}
```

and *bars* functions are counterparts of  your `push_back` method.

```
template <typename T>
void bar1 (T&& value) {
    process (move(value));   // you use move in your push_back method 
}

template <typename T>
void bar2 (T&& value) {
    process (forward<T>(value));
}
```

now we must consider 4 cases:

[1] pass L-value, version with forward

```
Foo f(20);
bar2 (f);
cout << (f.i) << endl; // 20
```

[2] pass R-value, version with forward

```
Foo f(20);
bar2 (move(f));
cout << (f.i) << endl; // 0, it is OK bacuse we wanted to move 'f' object
```

[3] pass R-value, version with move

```
Foo f(20);
bar1 (move(f));
cout << (f.i) << endl; // 0, ok, we wanted to move 'f' object
```

[4] pass L-value, version with move in your push_back method

```
Foo f(20);
bar1 (f);
cout << (f.i) << endl; // 0 !!! is it OK ? WRONG
```

in last case, we passed `f` as L-value, but this object was moved in `bar1` function, for me this is strange behavior and is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, inside my `push_back` function, why couldn't I simply do `new(data + size) T(std::move(value));` instead of using `std::move` only when calling `push_back`?

Comment: You cannot use `move` inside your _push_back_ method bacuse `move` always returns R-reference. Return type of `forward` depends on a type of `value`. When you call _push_back_ with L-value (you pass `a` object using `.push_back(a)` ) you will get L-reference as type of `value`, and it is ok, because you don't want to move `value` object inside your _push_back_ method. When you call `push_back` with R-value ( you pass 'a' using `.push_back(move(a))`), `value` will have R-reference type and move constructor could be invoked.

Comment: It's odd, I have changed just that, i.e. `std::move()` where before I had `std::forward<U>()` and works perfectly now. I have been using the whole day without any noticeable issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to perform a memmove with objects in C++.
You can find more information here [Will memcpy or memmove cause problems copying classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135769/will-memcpy-or-memmove-cause-problems-copying-classes)

If this is C++11 onwards, then what you want to use is placement new and the move constructor.   (you could probably just bin the placement new though unless you really want to keep allocating memory yourself)

If this is any other version of C++ then you'll have to just accept that that either you're going to have to copy the object (like the rest of the stl) or that your object will have to implement a function like `void moveTo(T& other)`